# How to get the sharepoint website url in a workflow from the current SPListItem?

Tags: splistitem, url

I am using sharepoint 2010 and have created a workflow in vs. In this workflow I create some tasks and fill the title, bodytext and assign it to a user or group. In the bodytext I add an hyperlink as "a href". I try to get the link from the current item. The problem is that sometimes the link is not correct because the hostname is missing. This is the code:

```
SPListItem currentItem = workflowProperties.Item;
    string itemURL = currentItem.ParentList.DefaultDisplayFormUrl + "?ID=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(currentItem.ID.ToString());

    workflowProperties.Web.Site.WebApplication.Sites[0].Url + itemURL
```

Sometimes is works and than this is the hyperlink:

```
http://mywebsite.com/sites/RFC/Lists/Wijzigingsverzoeken/DispForm.aspx?ID=28
```

And sometimes it the link is not working, and is it like this:

```
sites/RFC/Lists/Wijzigingsverzoeken/DispForm.aspx?ID=28
```

It looks like the problem is inside this piece of code:

```
workflowProperties.Web.Site.WebApplication.Sites[0].Url
```

Does someone know where the problem is? Or what the best practice is to get the sharepoint website url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you not use [SPWorkflowActivationProperties.WebUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.workflow.spworkflowactivationproperties.weburl.aspx) ?

```
string url = workflowProperties.WebUrl;
```

or

```
string url = workflowProperties.Web.ServerRelativeUrl;
```

Comment: Is this also gets the curren sitecollection url? I would like to get the current site collection url. For example:

http://mywebsite.com/sites/RFC

Comment: use workflowProperties.Site.Url or workflowProperties.Site.ServerRelativeUrl depend on you needs. The Site is an object that represents current site collection.

Comment: WHy this one gives sometimes an empty string?? string url = workflowProperties.Web.ServerRelativeUrl;